# Error with Codeigniter HMVC validation callback

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter with HMVC .
When I validate my form, I use the solution to fix the callback problem in HMVC :

1.Extends CI_Form_validation:

```
<?php
    // application/libraries/My_Form_validation.php

    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public $CI;

    }

?>
```

1. In my Controller :

class User extends MX_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent :: __construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->CI = & $this;

}
```

My problem is: in my localhost, everything is ok: callback validation run normally. But when I upload my project on host, i execute my controller it appears blank. When I comment the line

```
 //$this->form_validation->CI = & $this;
```

The controller run normally again.

Could you tell me how i fix this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: A blank page is usually a fatal error, show us the error in your error log.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error logs for any fatal errors, also you should extend my form validation this manner

```
    class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
       private $CI

      function My_Form_validation($config = array()) {

        parent::__construct($config); 
        $this->CI = &get_instance()

    }

   //example functions
  function my_custom_validation(str){ //or override , for example, required
      if($this->CI->method_from_instance()){
        return true;
       }
     return false
  }

}
```

and then use form_validation as you normally do, but now you have extra rule my_custom_validation

**EDIT**: if by any chance and for some wired reason you want to use controller functions in your library (aka $this) pass it as a config, once you load the library e.g. `$this->load->library('form_validation', array(('ci'=>$this)` //but i don't see why would you do that.